# By is not getting recognized while using driver.find_elements in selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, unrecognized-selector

[image: I was using selenium automation for web scraping while i notice that when i'm fetching an element of a search bar using its XPATH, "By" is not getting recognized. What am i doing wrong here?]

I was trying to fetch an element using its XPATH and was expecting for the result to get print

Answer (score 3):

You are missing an import

```py
from selenium.webdriver.common.by import By
```

Comment: Thank you very much, thought it all got imported just by one